How to hide loaded modules from variable inspection in VSCode (debug mode)
Unlike Spyder, where the option is supported and straightforward to find, I am unable to hide the modules from the (local and global) variable inspector in VSCode while in debug mode.
See image below as a small example of what I would like to get rid of (in red):

I am currently using VSCode 1.9.1 for Windows. My launch.json configuration file is the following:
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python: Current File",
            "type": "debugpy",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "console": "integratedTerminal",
            "justMyCode": false,
            "env": {
                "PYTHONPATH": "${workspaceFolder}:${env:PYTHONPATH}",
            }
        }
    ]
}

Importantly, I want to keep the setting "justMyCode": false as it is.

If it helps, I'm pretty sure justMyCode is irrelevant since it means what stack frames the debugger should step into, not what variables should be shown. (The modules are "your" variables anyway since the names are defined in "your" code.)

I just tried it for myself and I noticed that imported functions are nested under "function variables" but modules aren't nested under anything. That seems strange, like it seems like there should be a "modules" section. That could be a feature request :) Here's a related one: Provide a way to filter variables

Hello, you might be able to try updating the vscode version. If you want to ignore the module without changing the "justMyCode": false setting. You can try using the filters property to exclude. In the settings. json file to add "filter":{ "include":[], "exclude":["**/site-package/**"]}. where exclude specifies the excluded modules.

@Jeanneli Please don't post answers in the comments; post an answer instead. In the process, could you expand on the fitlers property? I checked and it's not available on its own on my system, so does it need to nest under another one? A link to documentation would also be great.

Sorry, I just suggested this setup and see if it works. It is also a setting that is added to the "settings.json" file.
